# Diffusion on a graph and its dual

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Is there a relation between the diffusion of a random walker on a planar graph and that on the dual of the graph? It seems perhaps intuitive that if the diffusion on the graph is slow (in comparison with the square lattice), that on the dual should be fast and vice-versa. Is this the case?